# How can i reload imageview in thread?

Tags: android

I'm trying to display several Images dynamically. After retrieving a url from xml parsing, I convert it to a Bitmap and loaded in image view using `setImageBitmap` in AsyncTask ,but current url image does not loaded but next url images loaded,whenever call next url,so i want to refresh or reload imageview in AsyncTask?.is it possible? possible please give code for me..

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use Droid-fu's [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/).

Comment: @ i want to only ImageView,have any possible in image view? Thanks